# McCrary / DCdensity graph

Tags: graph, stata, density-plot

I also posted this question to Statalist. However, my advisor later recommended me to post my question here.

I would like to graphically depict that there is no bunching around accounting related employee thresholds in my dataset. To do this, I want to implement the McCrary-test via the user-written Stata command DCdensity.

The number of employees is my running variable and the accounting threshold lies at 50. Therefore, my code is:

```
DCdensity employees, breakpoint(50) generate(Xj Yj r0 fhat se_fhat)
```

Graphical results are displayed in the first image below. In order to zoom in around the threshold, I use the code provided by William Lisowski on Statalist.

```
local breakpoint 50
local cellmpname Xj

local cellvalname Yj
local evalname r0
local cellsmname fhat
local cellsmsename se_fhat
drop if `cellmpname' < 0 | `cellmpname' > 500
drop if `evalname' < 0 | `evalname' > 500
tempvar hi
quietly gen `hi' = `cellsmname' + 1.96*`cellsmsename'
tempvar lo
quietly gen `lo' = `cellsmname' - 1.96*`cellsmsename'
gr twoway (scatter `cellvalname' `cellmpname', msymbol(circle_hollow) mcolor(gray)) (line `cellsmname' `evalname' if `evalname' < `breakpoint', lcolor(black) lwidth(medthick)) (line `cellsmname' `evalname' if `evalname' > `breakpoint', lcolor(black) lwidth(medthick)) (line `hi' `evalname' if `evalname' < `breakpoint', lcolor(black) lwidth(vthin)) (line `lo' `evalname' if `evalname' < `breakpoint', lcolor(black) lwidth(vthin)) (line `hi' `evalname' if `evalname' > `breakpoint', lcolor(black) lwidth(vthin)) (line `lo' `evalname' if `evalname' > `breakpoint', lcolor(black) lwidth(vthin)), xline(`breakpoint', lcolor(black)) legend(off)
```

Graphical results are displayed in the second image below.

Now to my questions:

- Graph 1: Why are there bins with a negative employee value (no
  negative employee values in the sample - I checked)? Those bins
  distort the graph in such way, that it seems there is a discontinuity
  even though there is none.
- Graph 2: Why is the graph partially gone? The same questions holds
  for the scatters?

Potential explanations - to be discussed:

- There are too few datapoints left of the threshold, i.e., between 0
  and 50, for DCdensity to draw the graph.
- r0 seems to be offset vs. Xj by about 300 (employees).

Graph 1
[image]

Graph 2
[image]